# Android Fragment overlapping each other and showing transparent view

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have an activity with a fragment container layout and in that layout i load a fragment A which has a listview (listview loads data from web). Now on clicking listview item i want to show detail view. For that i am loading another fragment B which is detail fragment. Now to do that first i used

```
FragmentTransaction ft = ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.fragmentsContainerLayout, new ScheduleDetailsFragment());
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();
```

But using replace remove the previous fragment A which contain listview and on pressing back it again reloads the onCreateView method of fragment A and its listview data. I want to prevent it from loading fragment A again (or sending call to webserver) on backpress. I want to maintain fragment A state and its listviews scroll position. To do that i used second option which is

```
FragmentTransaction ft = ((FragmentActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft.add(R.id.fragmentsContainerLayout, new ScheduleDetailsFragment());
                        ft.addToBackStack(null);
                        ft.commit();
```

If i use add() then Fragment B loads on top of Fragment A and Fragment A still visible. It shows both fragments overlapping each other and transparent. I also came across anothe solution which is to use show() and hide() methods. But i dont think that is an efficient way to achieve that. Can anyone suggest an effective solution?

Comment: You could call `ft.hide(YourListViewFragement)` - and call `ft.show(..)` in your activities `onBackPressed`. I do not know what happens with your scroll state. But the better solution would be to store your list + scroll position and let the fragment reload with the data.

Comment: you have to do `android:clickable="true"` in fragment xml root layout and `android:background="#FFFFFF"`.

Comment: @Amy previous fragment must not load again, because in that case it will again send call to webserver to get data for listview items. Yes i know about show() and hide() methods. I know that is a workaround but i want a proper and more efficient way to achieve that

Comment: @ChiragSavsani i dont think that works in this scenario

Comment: A proper way to do this would be to store your data in your activity, and check for saved data in `onCreateView()` of your fragment on reload.

Comment: in that case using hide() and show() is more feasible than that